# Get access for native camera, photoes, calendar and voice recording with IBM Worklight

Tags: iphone, html, cordova, ibm-mobilefirst

I have to build a cross platform application(for iphone and android only) and want to use IBM Worklight for this. I'd like to know is it possible to get access for native camera, photoes, calendar and voice recording for iphone and android. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If my answer helped you resolve your problem, please mark as answered.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

Since IBM Worklight utilizes [Apache Cordova](http://cordova.apache.org/) (also known as "PhoneGap"), this allows you access to all that you have requested using JavaScript APIs provided to you by Cordova.

See the complete [API for Cordova v2.3](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.3.0/) (the version Worklight 5.0.6.1 currently supports) for a list of supported features.

To see how it all works in conjunction with Worklight, have a look at the [IBM Worklight Getting Started training material](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/getting-started.html), and more specifically: [Adding native functionality to hybrid apps with Apache Cordova](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/getting-started.html#cordova).